# Read text(data) in an images using c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, text-extraction

Is there a way to read text(numbers and letters) in an image using C# ? Is this possible and What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: It is called OCR (Optical Character Recognition). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-ocr-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ has some wrapper to use it in .NET, or, simpler:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/modi.aspx but you need to keep an eye to the license since it is a part of the Office suite. In both case you tipically need some pre processing for the image and, as a solution I did in the past, some post processors that using some ehuristict correct the mistaked words.