# Reading text from images in c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, ocr

I have a windows form application in which I will add image from which I have read the text of vehicle number plates into a textblock.

Which dll or technique could I use to achieve this. I've heard about OCR but I couldn't implement it successfully

Comment: i have no code.i have to start but i dont know which technique i should use

Comment: Yes you need an OCR library but giving advice on tools is off-topic here. Start your search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read text(data) in an images using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913373/read-textdata-in-an-images-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a libary like [Tesseract](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr/)

There are also many articles on codeproject if you want to implement it yourself
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3907/Creating-Optical-Character-Recognition-OCR-appli
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476142/Optical-Character-Recognition

Or you can use an analytic image libary like [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

See also [Where can i find a free .Net (C#) library that i can use to scan and OCR documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459013/where-can-i-find-a-free-net-c-library-that-i-can-use-to-scan-and-ocr-documen)